# Informatica lookup: Trying to find input value of output-only port

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In an Informatica (9.1.0) mapping, a Lookup Transformation, LKP_TARGET, is derived from a target table, TARGET.

The condition for the Lookup is:

> CUST_ID = in_CUST_ID

LKP_TARGET has a port `NewLookupRow` that is not part of the lookup (is not derived from the target table), has no associated expression, is output-only, and no other port in the lookup has an associated expression that references it.  Yet, the output value of this port is in the `Groups` condition of a Router Transformation.

I am unable to find how this port is getting the value it outputs.  Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NewLookupRow port is added automatically when you configure a dynamic lookup. Below is the relevant excerpt from Informatica manual.

> ### NewLookupRows
>
> When you configure a Lookup transformation to use a
>   dynamic cache, the Designer adds the NewLookupRow port to the
>   transformation. The Integration Service assigns a value to the port,
>   depending on the action it performs to the lookup cache.
>
> The following table lists the possible NewLookupRow values:
>
> ```
> NewLookupRow Value |  Description
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 0                  |  Integration Service does not update
>                    |  or insert the row in the cache.   
> 1                  |  Integration Service inserts the row into the cache.   
> 2                  |  Integration Service updates the row in the cache.
> ```
>
> When the Integration Service reads a row, it changes the lookup cache
>   depending on the results of the lookup query and the Lookup
>   transformation properties you define. It assigns the value 0, 1, or 2
>   to the NewLookupRow port to indicate if it inserts or updates the row
>   in the cache, or makes no change.
>
> The NewLookupRow value indicates how the Integration Service changes
>   the lookup cache. It does not change the row type. Therefore, use a
>   Filter or Router transformation and an Update Strategy transformation
>   to keep the target table and lookup cache synchronized.
>
> Configure the Filter transformation to pass new and updated rows to
>   the Update Strategy transformation before passing them to the cached
>   target. Use the Update Strategy transformation to change the row type
>   of each row to insert or update, depending on the NewLookupRow value.
>
> You can drop the rows that do not change the cache, or you can pass
>   them to another target.
>
> Define the filter condition in the Filter transformation based on the
>   value of NewLookupRow. For example, use the following condition to
>   pass both inserted and updated rows to the cached target:
>
> NewLookupRow != 0

Comment: Thanks so much. Figured it had to be native to Informatica. My references do not mention this.